# Not able to understand example code

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I was going through **emu 8086** examples and stuck to the following **thermometer.asm** code

```
#start=thermometer.exe#

; temperature rises fast, thus emulator should be set to run at the maximum speed.

; if closed, the thermometer window can be re-opened from emulator's "virtual devices" menu.



#make_bin#

name "thermo"

; set data segment to code segment:
mov ax, cs
mov ds, ax

start:

in al, 125

cmp al, 60
jl  low

cmp al, 80
jle  ok
jg   high

low:
mov al, 1
out 127, al   ; turn heater "on".
jmp ok

high:
mov al, 0
out 127, al   ; turn heater "off". 

ok:
jmp start   ; endless loop.
```

Can anyone explain what `#make_bin#` and `#start=thermometer.exe#` means. Also, why we don't need to configure the ports before using them.

Comment: Those are emu8086 directives (not part of x86 Assembly), so consult the documentation of emu8086.  ... about "configuring ports" .. not sure what you mean by that. The `out` instruction doesn't need any configuration, it will set the I/O bus according to the values. Whether the device reading the bus needs configuration, that's different topic, depends how the device is constructed and designed to operate, consult documentation of the device.

Comment: Next 3 URLs will help you : http://muhendislik.istanbul.edu.tr/elektrikelektronik/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Emu8086_tutorial.pdf , http://www.coval.net/teach/emu8086/helpfiles/compatibility.html , https://www.facebook.com/Emu8086-and-assembly-language-Tips-n-Tricks-152336431476411/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i supose that is a part of program.
this part does nothing who on or off the thermometer when it report a temperature.
the line #make_bin# is used to create .bin that sometime can be put into eprom.
while the line #start=thermometer.exe# run the program that read a temperature.
remember when you find #....# is alway a compiler directive.